# Requested runtime (python 3.8) is not available for this stack (heroku-18)

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app with Heroku, but it's not working... I have looked at a bunch of other posts on here with the same error, but I'm not finding what's wrong.

I have Python 3.8.5 installed on my machine which is supported by Heroku-18, but for whatever reason when I do "git push heroku master" it sees python 3.8:

```
-----> Python app detected
!     Requested runtime (python 3.8) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
!     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

I have the runtime.txt file with python-3.8.5:

```
python-3.8.5
```

I also checked the version on my PC specifically, and tried reinstalling to no success, either:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.8.5
```

And, again, it's supported as of July, 21st, 2020:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1833

I guess the question would be, how do I get Heroku to recognize that I have the correct version installed? I'm sure it's something small I'm overlooking, but I can't figure it out.

Here's my directory showing it's in the root directory:

```
/my_site (masterbranch)
$ ls
about_app/  
ckeditor/     
my_site/  
staticfiles/
blog_app/   
contact_app/  
home_app/   
media/         
static/      
templates/
requirements.txt
Procfile
Procfile.windows 
runtime.txt  
db.sqlite3  
manage.py*
```

runtime.txt:

```
$ cat runtime.txt
python-3.8.5
```

Comment: Is the `runtime.txt` you show above in the root directory of your project? Do you see any other files with that name? That error makes it look like your file contains `python 3.8`, not `python-3.8.5`.

Comment: Yes, it's in the root directory. I even tried putting it in the folder that contains settings.py, etc, but obviously that didn't work either, haha.

Comment: Well it looks like it's picking up `python 3.8` from _somewhere_. You're entirely sure about the file name, location, and content? Can you show a directory listing of your project?

Comment: Thanks. And would you please run `cat runtime.txt` and add that output to your question, too?

Comment: Added :)
Thanks for your patience; still working this out

Comment: Hrm. Weird. Do you have a buildpack explicitly configured? What does [`heroku buildpacks`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-buildpacks) return?

Comment: "livmadeio has no Buildpack URL set." Is what i see

Comment: Are you sure that the files you're showing are the same ones you're trying to push? What does `git status` return? What command are you running to deploy?